# find the integral of $f$ over $G(A)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

Let $(x,y)=G(u,v)=(u^2-v^2, 2uv)$, Consider the region $A$ defined by $$u^2+v^2\le1\text{ and } u\ge0, \text{  }v\ge0.$$

let $$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
find the integral of $f$ over the region $G(A)$, the problem is that I'm kinda confused with the variables, let's start with the region $A$, I suspect that $G(A)$ is defined by $$(u^2-v^2)+4u^2v^2=(u^2+v^2)^2\le 1\implies (u^2+v^2)\le 1$$
and $$u^2\ge v^2, \text{  }uv\ge 0$$
Hence $$\iint_\limits{G(A)}\frac{\,dy\,dx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=4\iint_\limits{A}{\,du\,dv}$$
the last integrand is form $(f○G)(u,v)$ times the jacobian determinant,
but now how can I construct the bounds of integration?

Comment: I didn't assume that. it comes from $u^2-v^2 \ge 0$,  @NinadMunshi

Comment: The condition was $u\geq 0$, not $x\geq 0$

Comment: Where is your Jacobian? Also, the image of $A$ under $G$ is the region $x^2+y^2\leq 1,y\geq 0$

Comment: sorry i forgot it @MatthewPilling

Comment: so it's just the interior of a semicircle @MatthewPilling